# Placement of ram in Intel Q67 Motherboard

Tags: memory

I have purchased a 4GB Ram Module.

In slot one currently resides 2gb of ram which came inclusive with the machine.

I've placed the 4GB Ram Module into Slot two.

The motherboard is an Intel Q67.

Photo:

[image: Photo]

Each slot is color coded, is where I have placed the ram correct?

I would immediately assume,yes as they are two different amounts and are on different channels.

My question is:

What would happen if

I had 4gb in Slot one (Blue)
I had 2gb in Slot two (Black)

Slot 3: FREE (Blue)
Slot 4: FREE (Black)

In relation to: Slot 3 & Slot 4.. Would I have to match those now? (Ie. would I expect bad news if I put a 8gb in slot 3? Or would the motherboard just not use dual channel)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation? Every time I did, the manual for a motherboard contained a section about how to place and what type of RAM to place. We deal with professional admins here. Can it be you consider yourself to be too professional to bother doing basic admin work?

Comment: If you place one module in SLOTA1 and one in SLOTB1 the system likely wouldn't boot.  Feel free to try it though.  Just trying to determine the purpose of this question, because you actually want to do something, helpful if you tell us what that is.

Answer (score -1):

You wont have dual channel by placing it at any combination. Dual channel required same amount of RAM. (i.e. 2x2G, 2x4G), but you are having one 2G and one 4G